# Calling XSJS file in SAPUI5 for writng data on HANA

Tags: service, odata, sapui5, hana

I'm trying to create a service to write data from a SAPUI5 frontend to HANA tables. 
As far as I checked, I believe this is not possible via OData Services. So I've found another way, sing an XSJS file with a SQL INSERT statement.

Now, my problem is using this in UI5. As with OData, I would use something like oModel.create but now I think this doesn't work like that.

Those anyone has a clue?

Thanks!

Eva

UPDATE:
After using the first answer, I tried to create an entry in a HANA Table, but I'm getting a 500 error. Here's the code of the xsjs file:

```
var data = '', conn = $.db.getConnection(), pstmt;  

        if($.request.body){
            data = $.request.parameters.get("firstName");   
        }

        var conn = $.db.getConnection();
        var pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( 'INSERT INTO "Z003HB1N"."T_TEST" (FIRSTNAME) VALUES(?)' );

        pstmt.setString(1,data);

        pstmt.execute();
        pstmt.close();

        conn.commit();
        conn.close();

        doResponse(200,'');

        $.response.contentType = 'text/plain';
        $.response.setBody('Upload ok');
        $.response.status = 200;
```

Any clue what might be wrong?

Comment: Regarding your second question you could have a look into [this post](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2014/12/02/sap-hana-sps-09-new-developer-features-new-xsjs-database-interface) which shows an example of your desired use case. Is `doResponse` defined somewhere or could this be a copy/paste mistake? By the way, using the Web IDE (which is under <server>/sap/hana/ide/) you should be able to debug your XSJS file. Since you are using GET you dont need the body check in your second code line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [`.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) calls to call your new oData service on HANA and use parameters to hand over the desired values to your .xsjs service.

Example:

```
var query = "firstName=Sherlock&lastName=Holmes"
jQuery.ajax({
    url : "url/to/your/Service.xsjs?" + query,
    success : function(response) {
        // will be called once the xsjs file sends a response
        console.log(response);
    },
    error : function(e) {
        // will be called in case of any errors:
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

On HANA you can access the provided parameters in your service like this:

```
var firstName = $.request.parameters.get("firstName");
var lastName = $.request.parameters.get("lastName");
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I've try, but I'm not sure if it's working. Do you know how can I make like a console.log in an xsjs file? That way I would now if it works. Plus, I've checked my console and it doesn't have any error, so, must be good! :) thanks

Comment: As far as I know you can not simply log to the console in xsjs files. However, you can simply answer your REST call. Try the following in your xsjs: `$.response.status = $.net.http.OK; $.response.setBody("Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName);` and check the answer in the success handler of your ajax call (see edited answer).

Comment: I am trying to send array of objects using ajax post but cant figure out how to access in hana.- This is the request I am making from SAPUI5 to hana xs     
                                     url: uploadUrl,
                              type: "POST",
                              data:{"field1":"Hi", "field2":"There"}